# PHP security: include and config.ini

Tags: php, security

I'm hosting a file "getBio.php" that can be accessed directly:

```
http://www.example.com/getBio.php
```

I'm wondering if there is any difference in security effectiveness between:

A)

```
<?php

$config = parse_ini_file('../secretstuff/config.ini');

include '../secretstuff/getBio_B.php';

?>
```

B)

```
<?php 

include '../secretstuff/getBio_B.php';

?>
```

Where the line:

```
 $config = parse_ini_file('../secretstuff/config.ini');
```

is moved into the external file, getBio_B.php.

Thanks for any help,
Adam.

Comment: I don not know your purpose, but I think if you can ensure the origin of  `config.ini` and `getBio_B.php`(usually files in your project), the are safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your purpose, but I think if you can ensure the origin of  `config.ini` and `getBio_B.php`(usually files in your project), they are same.

If you just want to load some config items, use `parse_ini_file` is safer than `include`, because `include` function will load and execute loaded file's code,
it means whatever php code in loaded file the `include` function will execute it,
but use `parse_ini_file` to load some config, the structure of the ini file must have same structure as the php.ini's.

That's why evidently use config.ini having more security than include php file.